# How can I convert sperated date string to consecutive date string

Tags: javascript, java, mysql, date

I have date data. It can be Mysql data, Java array list or javascript json array.

```
[
{
    start=2015-07-02,
    id=3
},
{
    start=2015-07-03,
    id=4
},
{
    start=2015-07-06,
    id=5
},
{
    start=2015-07-07,
    id=8
}
]
```

I want to make like "2015-07-02", "2015-07-03 ~ 2015-07-06", "2015-07-07".
If there is empty date between date to date, I want to make connected string like "2015-07-03 ~ 2015-07-06".

And also, I'm using MySql, Java Spring, HTML, jQuery.....
Which part is proper to make connected date string effectively.
I need your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the difference in milliseconds between consecutive dates to check if there is more than a day difference. Assuming the dates are sorted in increasing order (earliest to latest) and there are no repeats, if the difference between consecutive dates is not a single day then we can assume that it's establishing a date range.

You can find some JavaScript code that prints accomplishes this.

```js
var dates = [{ start:'2015-07-02', id:3 }, { start:'2015-07-03', id:4 }, { start:'2015-07-06', id:5 }, { start:'2015-07-07', id:8 }];

var dateRangeString = '';

for ( var i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {

  if (i === dates.length-1) {
    dateRangeString += '"' + dates[i].start + '"';
  } else {
    var currentDate = new Date(dates[i].start);
    var nextDate = new Date(dates[i+1].start);

    if (nextDate.getTime() - currentDate.getTime() == 86400000) {
      dateRangeString += '"' + dates[i].start + '", ';
    } else {
      dateRangeString += '"' + dates[i].start + ' ~ ' + dates[i+1].start + '", ';
      i++;
    }
  }
}

// dateRangeString has your dates and date ranges.
// "2015-07-02", "2015-07-03 ~ 2015-07-06", "2015-07-07"
```